# Fast replacement of numpy values

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am trying to replace multiple values in a numpy array.

Basically, I have two arrays : zones.shape = 1289 ; indices.shape = (1289*1289,2)

*I want to replace "values of `indices`" by "index of `zones`"*

Here you have the arrays:

```
In [223]: indices
Out[223]: 
array([[   1,    1],
   [   1,    2],
   [   1,    3],
   ..., 
   [1289, 1287],
   [1289, 1288],
   [1289, 1289]])

zones = np.unique(indices)
```

In that case, indices responds to a series, but it could not be the case.

For now, all what I have found is:

```
for zone_ in range(len(zones)):
         indices[indices == zones[zone_]] = zone_
```

And it takes too much time with 1300 rows, the number could definitely be greater. Should I use dict? Do you see any numpy tricks, I have missed?

NB: I have searched, there are several post with a close issue, but nothing like I need.

Comment: That doesn't look like a 1289-by-2 array. That looks a lot bigger.

Comment: You're right that's a (1289*1289,2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question, you can get what you want from `np.unique` by returning the "inverse" along with the unique elements.  The inverse is flattened, so you have to reshape it back to the shape of `indices`.  For example,

```
In [14]: indices
Out[14]: 
array([[ 1,  1],
       [ 1,  2],
       [ 1,  3],
       [ 5,  1],
       [ 5,  3],
       [ 5, 10],
       [13, 10],
       [13, 13],
       [13, 14]])

In [15]: zones, inv = unique(indices, return_inverse=True)

In [16]: zones
Out[16]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  5, 10, 13, 14])

In [17]: new_indices = inv.reshape(indices.shape)

In [18]: new_indices
Out[18]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [3, 0],
       [3, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 4],
       [5, 5],
       [5, 6]])
```

Comment: Great ! You are right:
  `unique_inverse : ndarray, optional
    The indices to reconstruct the (flattened) original array from the unique array. Only provided if return_inverse is True.`